# Echo array into string, not showing array map

Tags: php, arrays, xml, xmlhttprequest

I have a portion of my php code that takes this example array

arrayxvalues = 1,2,3,4

```
if($_POST['arrayxvalues']!=""){    
 $wrapxforecast = array_map(
  function ($elements) {return "<xml>{$elements}</xml>";},$arrayxvalues);
 $stringxvalue = implode("",$wrapxvalue);
 echo $stringvalue;
}
```

The end result should echo `<xml>1</xml><xml>2</xml><xml>3</xml><xml>4</xml>`, but I instead get an echo that shows `1234`. Does anyone know why an echo would leave out the wrapping elements?

Comment: You're probably viewing it in a browser, which will **RENDER** the xml tags. Do a `view source` and you'll get your xml tags.

Comment: Hahaha, oh man... you're right.

Comment: @JosephCasey You can safely delete the question then I guess

Comment: You can have the PHP output be plain text by putting `header("content-type: text/plain");` in the source; that way, the browser will simply show the rendered text instead of trying to parse as HTML.